# Confirmation Box in SPItemEventReceiver class

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2007, messagebox

I want to display a confirmation box in [`SpItemEventReceiver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx) class using just C# or any script or plugin (e.g. jQuery) with it.

I have researched the problem and I believe that I can do something like build a string and display it on this item adding form but I read it in [this SharePoint King blog post](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/06/redirection-from-event-handler.html) (I am NOT advertising them) that it's not possible if you search for the text. Here's an excerpt:

> **Is there any way we can show a custom message box when an event is
>   fired and continue with the event?**
>   No, that is not possible from the method described here.
>   You can put alert on button click of the form by the javascript but
>   can not be done by an event handler.

I wonder if someone can confirm whether can or we can't do it, as I think we can but don't know how. Here's a piece of code I'm trying:

```
class className: SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            this.DisableEventFiring();
            //Display a Message box here
```

**[Edit:]** Will the `HttpContext.Response` property work in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing a message box won't work here; if it worked the message box would be shown on the server because that's where this code runs. What you could use server-side is the SharePoint

Page Status [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.sppagestatussetter%28v=office.14%29.aspx)